# Force a Refresh in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, refresh

So I have a expandablelistview, and all of the children of one of the parents ("checked in" is the name of the parent) have a button that says "checked out", and when you click that button it send a rest put call (json) and basically it checks them out and on our server it will then put them in the next parent ("departed")...so when the button is clicked, the call is done instantly and the record is changed in the database, however, the UI does not refresh unless the user pulls down to refresh so I need to force a refresh when this call is being done.

I am using SwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 0):

So far what i understood from the question is you need to refresh the listview and UI when database update happens.. if you want to achieve this you need to implement cursor and loader

please refer the following links

https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/

Comment: I need to refresh the listview/UI when someone clicks a button that does a REST call

Comment: @ilikeicecreamsandwiches yes, you can achieve this easily with cursors and loaders

Comment: So it is an issue with ExpandableListAdapter, when I click the button I now delete my child row and then call notifyDataSetChanged() and manually call my SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh, problem is that it deletes the row and then adds it back because the by the time the JSON call is done, the refresh is already done so if it could wait like 5 more seconds, it would work